# I don't understand the "share" concept in miner and pool

Tags: mining, shares

If I launch a miner, after a few minutes it displays "shares: 65", 65 acepted. But pool statistics shows me "valid shares 23, stale shares 0, invalid shares 2". Last seen 12 minutes ago, but the miner can't found 40 shares in 12 minutes.... Where gone the shares?.

Comment: Please provide an example of the scenario you are talking about so we can provide a better answer. :)